# JDT - IVariableBinding - How to get VariableDeclaration(Fragment)?

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I want to get default value of a variable.

```
SimpleName varName = ...; // the use of a variable
IVariableBinding declBinding = varName.getVariableDeclaration();
// ??? what is the next step?
```

In debugger I see correct declaration (toString is called), but I don't know how to get actual declaration (ASTNode which actually will be VariableDeclarationFragment or just VariableDeclaration)?

Comment: From where do you get the SimpleName??

Comment: @Subhankar, from the generated CompilationUnit by the ASTParser (standard way)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the default value in this way :

```
SimpleName varName = ...; // the use of a variable    
IVariableBinding b= (IVariableBinding) node.resolveBinding();
Object o= b.getVariableDeclaration().getConstantValue();
```

If the variable is a primitive data-type u-you will get the wrapper equivalent of the type.

Comment: It works only if the declaration contains `final` keyword. If not, it returns `null` to me